# Response.Output.Write how to bold specific words

Tags: vb.net, response.write

Below is my example in VB. I want it to only bold the  objects and not the rest of the string. What am I missing?

```
Response.Output.Write("Sample text i am writing: <br/> obj1: <b>{0}<b/> <br/> obj2: <b>{1}<b/>", obj1, obj2)
```

It looks like this:

```
  Sample text i am writing:
  obj1: **obj1
  obj2: obj2**
```

I want it to look like this:

```
  Sample text i am writing:
  obj1: **obj1**
  obj2: **obj2**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using wrong end tag, end tag for bold is `</b>` not `<b/>`

```
 Response.Output.Write("Sample text i am writing: <br/> obj1: <b>{0}</b> <br/> obj2: <b>{1}</b>", obj1, obj2)
```